# Low Pass filtering

Tags: raytracing

Is it possible that low pass filtering can be applied to Ray tracing ?

My guess is that since after the algorithm runs we have an image then low pass filtering helps in order to prevent aliasing from happening. Yet, I am not sure about this. Can someone elaborate on that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Low-pass filtering is a classic tool from signal theory that will effectively remove noise, as you suggested, but will also cancel out desired high-frequency information in the image such as sharp edges. The image will look blurry.

Post-filtering Monte Carlo rendering results is an open field of research and many advances have been made over the years, and overview of which can be found in the *Denoising Your Monte Carlo Renders: Recent Advances in Image-Space Adaptive Sampling and Reconstruction* SIGGRAPH Course [here](http://cgg.unibe.ch/publications/denoising-your-monte-carlo-renders).

Answer (score 5):

David Kuri's answer yields a modern approach, but a simple-to-implement solution is to explicitly supersample with jittering. Classic paper: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15869-f11/www/readings/cook86_sampling.pdf.

Comment: Note that there is a fundamental difference: supersampling (with jittering or any other technique) requires _additional samples_, while a post-filter (like the suggested low-pass filter) works on the _rendered image_. Nevertheless, this is valuable additional information and both techniques go hand in hand.

Comment: I answered initially without seeing yours (antialias with some kind of stochastic supersampling), but your answer was better. I still thought the older paper was still worth referencing, so I changed my answer instead of deleting it. I hope that's reasonable etiquette?

Comment: Totally, your answer is a fine addition :) I just wanted to make sure nobody gets confused.

Comment: Understood. It really sinks in that aliasing is a result of the initial samples being at regular intervals: if every sample hits the pickets of a fence, you're stuck with a white wall. Applying a low pass filter to a regularly sampled image just isn't universally effective (the high frequency picket fence aliases down to a low frequency artifact - a white wall).

Comment: The post filtering approach also seems like a really interesting modern CPU (with integrated GPU) load balancing question. Ray trace using CPU cores, which walk such data structures efficiently, post process the images on the GPU. Fun project!